# SCVMM An upgrade is available for Virtual Machine Manager agent version 3.0.6005.0 on the computer

Tags: hyper-v

Today we validate each server's status and all are shown as "need actions".

### Warning details:

> Warning (20510) An upgrade is available for Virtual Machine Manager
>   agent version 3.0.6005.0 on the computer %servername%.
>
> Recommended Action Update the VMM agent, and then try the operation
>   again.

Any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/120e50bf-978b-47bd-9c07-6dc7628f8b92/scvmm-with-hyperv-agent-communication-is-blocked-virtualization-software-or-vmm-agent-is?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv), we found there are two agents on SCVMM server:
3.0.6005.0 and 3.0.6019.0 under C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\agents\amd64.

We installed the 3.0.6019.0 agents.

At the beginning, I install it with just administrator right. And the issue can't be fixed.

Then I tried to install it with the VMM user who has the administrator role and VMM role both.

The solution is failed.

Then at last I remove the host and re-add the host.

The issue is fixed and the agent is upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score -1):

from SCVMM

1. In the Managed Computers node of Administration view, select the
   managed computers on which you want to update the agent.
2. In the Actions pane, click Update Agent. The Update Agent action is
   enabled only when the version of the agent on a managed computer is
   older than the version of the VMM server.
3. In the Update Agent dialog box, type the credentials of a domain
   account with administrator privileges on the selected managed 
   computers, and then click OK.