# SCVMM - can't add vm library from a host

Tags: hyper-v

Today I try to add a host as library host. But when the steps complete, it will refresh and gone in the library list.

Later I find the following error in job:

> Error (408)
>   *ServerName* has an unsupported version of the Virtual Machine Manager agent installed.
>
> Recommended Action Uninstall the Virtual Machine Manager agent using
>   Add or Remove Programs on *ServerName*, and then try the operation
>   again.

But Yesterday I failed to upgrade the scvmm agent manually. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371971/scvmm-an-upgrade-is-available-for-virtual-machine-manager-agent-version-3-0-6005/20372049#20372049)

Also I tried the uninstall and install method and still failed.

Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fix the scvmm agent issue with solution in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371971/scvmm-an-upgrade-is-available-for-virtual-machine-manager-agent-version-3-0-6005/20372049#20372049)

The issue is fixed.